# graphstream FileSinkSVG2

Tags: java, graphstream

I am creating a graph with graphstream and writing the result to an svg-file using FileSinkSVG2. Works well. The only problem is that arrows at the end of the edges are not showing up as they should according to the css defintion. Any suggestions? Here is my code.

```
        System.setProperty("gs.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");          

        String path = "C:\\test.svg";
        Graph graph = new MultiGraph("GraphStream");

        graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", "url('https://www.test.de/graph.css')");

        Layout layout = new HierarchicalLayout();

        graph.addSink(layout);
        layout.addAttributeSink(graph);

        setGraphValues(resultMap, graph);

        layout.compute();

        while (layout.getStabilization() < 1) {
            layout.compute();
        }           

        FileSinkSVG3 svg = new FileSinkSVG3();

        try {

            svg.writeAll(graph, path);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info(ex.getMessage(), ex);
           return;
        }
```

CSS-File:

```
graph {
    fill-color: white;
}

node {
    size: 100px, 50px;
    shape: rounded-box;    
    fill-color: white;
    stroke-mode: plain;
    stroke-color: red;
    text-visibility-mode:normal;
    text-color:black;
    text-background-color:white;
    text-style:normal;
    text-alignment:center;
    text-size:18px;
}


edge {
arrow-shape:arrow;
arrow-size: 3px, 2px; 
shape: line;
size: 2px;
fill-color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, it seems that FileSinkSVG2 does not support custom edges, including arrows and shapes. You can open an issue in [github](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-core/), or propose your own implementation in a [pull request](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-core/pulls).